# Angular js audio issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to pause angular js audio when browser window is closed and resume again when window is maximized?
This is my code. i am new to angular js . i have got no idea about it. anyone help me

```
    var app=angular.module("myApp",['ngAudio']);
    app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,ngAudio,$window)
    {$scope.src="aud.mp3";
        $scope.play=false;
        $scope.play=function(){
            $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('aud.mp3');
            $scope.audio.play();
        }
        $scope.stop=function(){
            $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('aud.mp3');
            $scope.audio.pause();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below logic, which will track `visibilitychange` event and check for document visibility.

**Code**

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, ngAudio, $window, $document) {
    $scope.src = "aud.mp3";
    $scope.play = false;
    $scope.play = function() {
        $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('aud.mp3');
        $scope.audio.play();
    };
    $scope.stop = function() {
        $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('aud.mp3');
        $scope.audio.pause();
    };

    $document[0].addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        var doucmentHidden = document.hidden;
        $scope.$apply(function() { //need to apply scope from events to run digest cycle
            if (doucmentHidden)
                $scope.stop();
            else
                $scope.play();
        });
    }, false);
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdytUOfgBIsPz1ZiZJT8?p=preview)

Comment: Nice solution. One small suggestion: changing the variable name to `documentHidden` (or `isHidden` or similar) might be less confusing given that you're setting it equal to `document.hidden`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but i am getting error after adding your code that "$ is not defined". i did not include jquery plugin . i need to do everything in angular js

Comment: @Vinothkanna it doesn't jquery at all, did you injected $document dependency on controller level

Comment: @Bryan I did change variable name as you suggested, Thanks :)

Comment: sorry i can't understand.can u please explain how to inject $document ??

Comment: now i am getting an error  'undefined is not a function'. i think the problem is with addEventListener. does angularJs has this method??

Comment: do change `$document[0]` instead `$document`, see updated code in answer

Comment: @Vinothkanna check I've added working plunkr for your solution..did you check the plunkr?

Comment: but this solution is not working in iPad browsers when i minimize the browser window. but it works when i open a new tab in the browser

Comment: @Vinothkanna you didn't mention anywhere in question that you wanted to work it in IPAD too.. You could open new question there..i'd love to help there.. Thanks :)

Comment: oh yea.. i thought it would be work fine in iPad browsers too.. sorry for that can u plz tell me??

Comment: @Vinothkanna Can you please ask new question, so that other people also could help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342781/angular-js-audio-issue-in-mobile-browsers-and-ipad